# How can I find the minimum of a multi-dim function that can be written as sum of absolute values

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, absolute-value

for a certain application I need to implement an algo that finds the minimum of a function of the following form.
It´s a function of the variables $x_{i}$:

$$\sum_{p} a^{p}| \sum_{i} b_{i}^{p}x_{i}+c_{i}^{p}| $$

It´s convex and I figured out the one dimensional case but got stuck here. Anybody has a clue?

Comment: What set does $p$ range over in the sum? [positive integers, primes, or what?] Also are there finitely many $x_i$ ?

Comment: p is just an index, no exponentitation here. both index sets are finite.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is non-negative, you can move those into the absolute value and after some reordering you essentially have a regression problem with an L1 cost $|Dx+e|_1$. You either solve that as a linear program, or use tailored algorithm for L1 regression.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I read a bit about linear programming and will try it this way.

Comment: Note that an algorithm to minimize this is very easy to implement, LP might be severe overkill (unless you already work in an environment where you have readily available solvers, and you don't care about complexity, such as simply playing around in MATLAB)